# DependencyProperty validation is not called from data template (only in .NET 4.0)

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, user-controls, datatemplate

### There is a problem in .NET 4.0, which does not exist in 3.5 (have not tested earlier or later frameworks).

I have created a demo user control, which has only a single property Num (of type Integer):

```
Public Class UserControl1

Public Shared NumProperty As DependencyProperty = _
            DependencyProperty.Register("Num", _
                                        GetType(Integer), _
                                        GetType(UserControl1), _
                                        New PropertyMetadata(defaultValue:=0, _
                                                PropertyChangedCallback:=New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnNumPropertyChanged), _
                                                CoerceValueCallback:=New CoerceValueCallback(AddressOf OnNumPorpertyCoerce)), _
                                        New ValidateValueCallback(AddressOf IsNumValid))

Public Property Num As Integer
    Get
        Return GetValue(NumProperty)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        SetValue(NumProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared Function IsNumValid(value As Object) As Boolean
    If value IsNot Nothing And TypeOf value Is Integer Then
        If CInt(value) < 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
    End If

    Return True
End Function

Public Shared Sub OnNumPropertyChanged(sender As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    ' do nothing here
End Sub

End Class
```

So, basically, you can not set anything smaller than zero to Num.

### The question

When I use this control in WPF window and try to set Num=-1, I get the exception.
However if I try to use this control as part of DataTemplate, and also set Num=-1, **there is no excepetion** raised.

I have tried to put a breakpoint in Validation procedure of my user control, but it is hit only in case of user control in window, and it is not hit if I have user control in DataTemplate.

Can anybody explain why validation is not executed from DataTemplate?

P.S. you can find related thread on Microsoft's forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f7fd05a5-cae3-496a-8abe-590541ecdd0a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Microsoft solves this problem (upvote at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742083/dependencyproperty-validation-is-not-called-from-data-template), workaround may be used:

In your coercion function call validation function (leave validation function for all those cases then it is called). And if the validation result is False, raise an System.ArgumentException with a message of such pattern: '%INVALID VALUE%' is not a valid value for property '%PROPERTY_NAME%'. By providing such code you will provide user of your user control with same information he or she would get from regular validation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this all seems to be working fine... I get validation errors in case of normal hosting and also in case of templated hosting of the user control!

**User Control XML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContentControlTest.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentControlTest">
    <StackPanel>        
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Num,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                       AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}},
                 ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                 NotifyOnValidationError=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,
                 UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**User Control Code Behind:**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Num",
            typeof (int),
            typeof (UserControl1),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                0, NumPropertyChangedCallback,
                NumCoerceValueCallback), NumValidateValueCallback);

    public static void NumPropertyChangedCallback
           (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var i = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValue);
    }

    public static object NumCoerceValueCallback
                 (DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(baseValue) < 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return baseValue;
    }

    public static bool NumValidateValueCallback(object value)
    {
        var i = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        return i >= 0;
    }

    public int Num
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.GetValue(NumProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(NumProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Window XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:usrctrl="clr-namespace:ContentControlTest;assembly=ContentControlTest"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>        
        <usrctrl:UserControl1 Margin="5" Num="-1"/>
        <Separator Margin="5"/>        
        <ItemsControl Margin="5">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                <x:ArrayExtension Type="{x:Type System:String}">
                    test
                </x:ArrayExtension>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <usrctrl:UserControl1 Num="-1"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>  
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If you compile the above Window.XAML code as it is, you will get a compilation exception itself, that **"-1" is not a valid value to set to the Num property** in **both** the data template based and the non-template user controls.

But if you remove the Num="-1" from both the user controls and then compile and run the aplication, it loads both the textboxes with default value of 0.

Now in the textboxes if you input -1 **both textboxes** turn red indicating that validation model is working on their inherent binding.

So I am not sure why should this not be working in your case!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, you understood the problem completely wright.  I have been using .NET 4.0 and just now I have tested with 3.5 - and validation works. Are you using 3.5? It seems like everything works in 3.5.

Comment: Yes I am using 3.5 You mean to say this same code compiled under 4.0 doesnt work? Let me check....

Comment: Yes even I observed that in 4.0 compilation errors only appear for non-template user control. But for the templated one, the coercion does the trick by showing 0 instead of -1. But interestingly if we skip coercion, -1 appears in the templated user control without red border though! So yes this is a bug in 4.0 mostly. Hence reocmmended practise is to use coercion, along with validation in 4.0!

Comment: I have opened a case on Microsoft's Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742083/dependencyproperty-validation-is-not-called-from-data-template Can you please upvote if you find this problem important?

Comment: Yes, I thought about the coercion. It is a solution, but it has one downside: user of my control will not know that he has passed in invalid value. Although coercion may throw an error if validation is not passed!

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding in WPF does not throw Exceptions, it just doesn't work when Exceptions occur. I have mixed feelings about this, but it surely makes debugging difficult. See [this article](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52) on how to implement Traceing. I bet you will see the error then.

Comment: Hi Dabblrnl, in this case the problem is not in the binding, as nothing is bound in the user control to anything from data item. Even more I should say - no errors are reported even in output/debug.